# Launching a Facebook page from an iPhone app via QR code

Tags: ios, facebook, qr-code

I'm trying to create a QR code that launches a Facebook page from the app, rather than the browser on both Android and iOS.

Creating the code with `fb://page/<page id>`, works perfectly on an Android.

This was also supposed to work with iOS's Facebook app, but I think since Facebook updated their app recently from a HTML5 version to a fully native iOS app, that functionality has stopped working. It indeed opens the Facebook app, but it does not go to the page.

Has anyone else seen this happen since the app was updated a few weeks ago? And what string would I have to use to create a working QR Code for iOS's Facebook app?

Comment: I would check Facebook's new developer documentation and see if they changed the path.

Comment: We finally figured it out. FB changed it to fb://profile/ instead of "pages". It works across both platforms.

Comment: Be sure to answer your question. Maybe you'll save someone else some trouble.

Answer (score 2):

We finally figured it out. FB changed it to fb://profile/ instead of "pages". It works across both platforms.